# jQuery UI filter, Full HTML and hook_block_view_VIEW_NAME_alter

Tags: 7, javascript, navigation

I have installed jQuery UI Filter and jQuery plugins to get text with accordion effect. It works perfectly when the content is inserted in a node, with a special tags language. However, when I try to get the text rendered in a block with **hook_block_view_VIEW_NAME_alter**, as I am just the **$data["content"]["#markup"]** property, it is not working and it is displaying the special tags without rendering them: [accordion], etc.

Must I get the effect by using clean jQuery instead of the modules? Is there a way of saying that I want to apply the "Full HTML" properties to the content-markup text of the block?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with the modules installed ( jQuery plugins , jQuery UI filter and jQuery UI filter accordion). The trick was to include the following Javascript in the template **yourtheme_preprocess_page()** and in the HTML use the div with id="accordion" of the official example ( https://jqueryui.com/accordion/ ).

```
drupal_add_js(' jQuery(function() {
var icons = {
  header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
  activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
};
jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  icons: icons
});
jQuery( "#toggle" ).button().click(function() {
  if ( jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" ) ) {
    jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", null );
  } else {
    jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", icons );
  }
});
  });', array('type' => 'inline'));
```